# Cleaning up an expression inside the controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a an angular app with data in JSON format like this:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Main",
        "Class": "class-o",
        "Base": 150,
        "Growth": 10
    },
    {
        "Name": "Time",
        "Class": "class-r",
        "Base": 1.2,
        "Growth": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "Value",
        "Class": "class-r",
        "Base": 35,
        "Growth": 3
    },
    {
        "Name": "Value/Time",
        "Class": "class-r",
        "Base": 35,
        "Growth": 3,
        "Mod": 1.2
    }
]
```

I have an `ng-repeat` to loop through this data:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="attr in ctrl.Attr">
        <span ng-class="attr.Class">{{attr.Name}}</span> {{(attr.Base+(attr.Growth*(ctrl.level-1)))*(attr.Mod?attr.Mod:1)}} - {{attr.Growth}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

These expressions take the `base` value, and add the `growth`*`level`. These expressions update in real time as the level changes as expected.

I would like to clean up the expressions inside the controller to clean up my html. But I'm facing two problems:

1. The Value/Time object is a combination of the "Time" and "Value" objects and is the only one with the "Mod" value. I've been trying to come up with a way to cut this extra object out. I've tried creating variables from the "Base" values but they don't bind the same way and don't update when the digest runs.
2. As mentioned above, if I create the expressions in the controller, and bind those to the html, they display, but don't update with the digest.

How can I get the appropriate expressions in the controller, and keep them updating?

**Update**
As per the comments, I attempted to modify the bind to

```
{{ctrl.getAttr(Attr.Name)}}
```

And added this function to my controller:

```
this.getAttr = function(attr){
    angular.forEach(ctrl.Attr, function(value){
        if(value.Name == attr){
            return value.Base+(value.Growth*(ctrl.level-1));
        }
    });
}
```

But nothing is displayed on the page with this.

**Clarification**

My first point is that the bit of the expression using the `Mod` value is a customized attribute added to the JSON. The JSON being imported into the app is:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Main",
        "Class": "class-o",
        "Base": 150,
        "Growth": 10
    },
    {
        "Name": "Time",
        "Class": "class-r",
        "Base": 1.2,
        "Growth": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "Value",
        "Class": "class-r",
        "Base": 35,
        "Growth": 3
    }
]
```

The Value/Time part is being added manually in the controller to make:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Main",
        "Class": "class-o",
        "Base": 150,
        "Growth": 10
    },
    {
        "Name": "Time",
        "Class": "class-r",
        "Base": 1.2,
        "Growth": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "Value",
        "Class": "class-r",
        "Base": 35,
        "Growth": 3
    },
    {
        "Name": "Value/Time",
        "Class": "class-r",
        "Base": 35,
        "Growth": 3,
        "Mod": 1.2
    }
]
```

The ideal solution would be to calculate the Value/Time and add it in without modifying the original JSON.

Comment: Typically, this kind of logic is done in the controller, and the View just has: `{{getCalculatedValue(attr)}}`

Comment: @NewDev exactly, but I've not been able to get that working so that it updates wit hthe digest

Comment: This function would be invoked on every digest and would just calculate the value... not sure what you mean otherwise

Comment: When I try using a function like that nothing is displayed

Comment: Well... add the code that you tried that didn't work. It works fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qv4AB3vbhreoggE8I78j?p=preview

Comment: No... you already have the actual `attr` object - no need for `forEach` to find it. Anyway, look at the plunker link

Comment: I see your method of implementation is different then mine, but it does only solve one of my problems.

Comment: What is the other problem?

Comment: @NewDev The initial JSON does not contain a 'Value/Time' object, I have to create it dynamically, and re-create an attribute list to loop through (not the original JSON). I passed the Name in an attempt to create a check for it, but that doesn't work either without the added element. Your method will work, but I still need a solution to problem #1.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what exactly the issue is there... and it is typically better to have one issue per question in SO

Comment: It is the same issue, which is how do I clean up my expression inside of my controller. I'll update my question with more clarification

Comment: @NewDev I've come to a solution based on your comments. If you write up an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to keep *some* basic logic in the View, but if the logic pertains to your app's functionality - and this sort of calculation does - then it is advised to perform it in the controller for reasons of testibility of code, readability of the View, and often DRY-ness.

So, instead, create a function that returns the calculated value for a given object `attr`:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="attr in ctrl.Attr">
    ...
    {{ctrl.calc(attr)}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
var vm = this;
vm.level = 10;
vm.calc = function(attr) {
  return (attr.Base + attr.Growth * (vm.level - 1))*(attr.Mod ? attr.Mod : 1);
};
```

Another point to note, since in your update you attempted to create a `getAttr` function, is that $watched function, e.g. `{{doSomething()}}` should be extremely fast - almost getters - (and must pure: idempotent and leave no side effects). So, it's highly recommended to avoid loops or complex calculations, since they will be executed on every digest cycle and can negatively affect performance.